# Missing Facebook like buttons (multiple)

Tags: facebook

I created a Facebook like button a year or so ago on their site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).
The site is still up, and it shows the button on their site when I try to create it, along with how many people have already liked it.

However, on my site's homepage, I've spent hours trying to get it to show up, thinking it might have been a glitchy css misplacing it. However, looking across my site, all my like buttons no longer work, as I had like buttons for different songs on my site, exc.
I know it's not just me either, because a site with game mods I go to no longer shows the like button any longer, either, though their programming has not changed any.

So my question is if anyone knows of they changed their coding so that the coding at the link mentioned above no longer works, and what would be the new code?

Code I'm using:

In Head:

```
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</HEAD>
```

In Body:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.alternategaming.net" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

Thanks for any information on this in advance... I'm wondering if it's my code, or if facebook just discontinued use....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, as of the time of that posting, the Facebook "Like" buttons have a problem with showing up on Google Chrome. I went to another site, and they didn't show up either, until I went there using Firefox.

Long story short: unless Facebook or Chrome fixes something, "Like" buttons don't work off of Facebook in Google Chrome; for anyone else with this problem to know. :)